# Как передать значения в виде "5;5" из json в параметры файла типа js

Tags: javascript, json

Есть файл типа json в нем хранятся размеры прямоугольника в виде "300;500"

```
{   "Rect": [
        {
        "name":"rect-1",
        "size":"300;500",
        },
        {
        "name":"rect-2",
        "size":"400;200",
        }
    ]
}
```

Эти данные передаются в файл типа js и сохраняются в массиве.
В файле js есть два параметра, которые хранят длину и ширину прямоугольника.

```
w_rect=arr[0].size;
h_rect=arr[0].size;
```

Нужно чтобы длина и ширина были равны данным из json соответственно.

Если задать вопрос кратко, то как разделить **size:"300;500"** и передать их в js в параметры **w_rect, h_rect**

Comment: методом split()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const sizes [w_rect, h_rect] = "300;500".split(";")
```

Comment: Если применить деструктизацию, то можно не выделять отдельную переменную в виде массива, а сразу всё сложить по переменным

Comment: Окей, мне просто было лень я написал самый простой вариант